# Silverlight Tree view

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, treeview

I am using the tree view control in my silverlight project. I use data binding for binding my model to the tree. This works perfect.

After adding some features to the tree I ran into two problems:

1. When I change a property on my Model, the tree does not get updated, even after my onproperty changed get called and also my converter is not called?(I need to hide the item when a specific property changes) (Answered)
2. How do I hide an Item in the tree? (I use Textbox + image as Item template)
3. Stack panel is hidden, but empty container remains in tree

**DataTemplate:**

```
                <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource ItemVisibleConverter} ,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
                    <controls:Label Name="myItem" Content="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource ItemConverter} ,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Black"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Converter:**
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, ystem.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           return GetVisibility(value);
        }

```
        private Visibility GetVisibility(object value)
    {
        bool IsVisible= (bool)value;
        if (IsAvailableForDownload)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsAvailableForDownload;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsAvailableForDownload = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "IsAvailableForDownload");
        }
    }

//Code for on property changed event
}
```

Regards

Comment: Can you post the Xaml where you setup the data binding (HierarchialDataTemplate for your tree) as well as a small part of the Model class showing your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged?  Posting the converter code would help too.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably need to make sure that your [model implements INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) so that the binding system can do its job.
2. Could you have a property of type Visibility that your item template binds to, or a bool plus a value converter that returns a Visibility value?

   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Visibility="{Binding ThisThingsIsVisible}">
           <Button Content="{Binding Blah}" />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>

I don't know if this is the recommended way or not - could your bound object not expose hidden items in their collections?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you very much. INotify solved my first problem, but I'm still struggling with number two and three. Any advice?

Comment: Running into an error, or looking for guidance on adding the visibility into the data object or view model?